# Why are we able to call the interface .ctor [base()], from the constructor of derived class - C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Following is the code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Manager : IEmployee
    {
        private int _empId;
        private string _empName;
        private string _location;
        public int EmpId
        {
            get
            {
                return _empId;
            }
            set
            {
                _empId = value;
            }
        }
        public string EmpName
        {
            get
            {
                return _empName;
            }
            set
            {
                _empName = value;
            }
        }
        public string Location
        {
            get
            {
                return _location;
            }
            set
            {
                _location = value;
            }
        }

        public Manager(int empId, string empName, string Location)
            : base()
        {
            this._empId = empId;
            this._empName = empName;
            this._location = Location;
        }

        public string GetHealthInsuranceAmount()
        {
            return "Additional Health Insurance Premium Amount is: 1000";
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the class `Manager` implements the interface `IEmployee`. And the interface should have no constructor.
So, how is it possible that the `Manager constructor` is able to call the `IEmployee constructor`?

Following is the `IEmployee interface`:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IEmployee
    {
        string GetHealthInsuranceAmount();

        int EmpId
        {
            get; set;
        }

        string EmpName { get; set; }

        string Location
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the calling Program:

```
using ClassLibrary1;
using System;

namespace InheritanceExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEmployee emp;

            emp = new Manager(1001, "Vikram", "USA");
            Console.WriteLine($"Managers EmpId: {emp.EmpId}. Name: {emp.EmpName}. Location: {emp.Location}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Manager's health insurance: {emp.GetHealthInsuranceAmount()}");

            //emp = new SalesMan(1002,"Sukhmeet","Austrailia");
            //Console.WriteLine($"SalesMan EmpId: {emp.EmpId}. Name: {emp.EmpName}. Location: {emp.Location}");
            //Console.WriteLine($"SalesMan's health insurance: {emp.GetHealthInsuranceAmount()}");

        }
    }
}
```

As shown above, following is the way, the `Manager class constructor`, is calling the `IEmployee interface constructor`:

```
public Manager(int empId, string empName, string Location)
    : base()
{
    this._empId = empId;
    this._empName = empName;
    this._location = Location;
}
```

Please see: I am using C# language version 7.3 (.Net Framework 4.8) - but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Remove the interface implementation and you'll see that `base()` still works. That's because it belongs to `Object`, not to the interface.

Comment: Except for `object`, all classes in .NET derive from exactly one class.  If a class declares no base class, it derives from `object` directly.  Your `IEmployee` isn't a class and doesn't get involved in this

Comment: I think this question starts from the incorrect assumption that a class implementing an interface is a derived class. It's not. It's a class that implements an interface

Comment: It _is_ a derived class though; it's derived from the `System.Object` class, and that's exactly why `: base()` works, @Camilo (I get what you're trying to say but this might confuse the OP).

Comment: @41686d6564 I disagree. The OP is already confused, and saying that it is a derived class because it inherits from Object is only going to make things worse, that's quite an extreme PoV

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto .Hi Camilo, no, I am not confused. I understand completely now, that the `Manager` class is inheriting implicitly from the `Object` class. The `IEmployee` is an interface and not a class - so the `Manager` class defaults to the `base` of `Object`, and not `IEmployee`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every class in C# derives from the `Object` base class.

The fact that C# uses the same keyword for class inheritance and interface implementation, the `:` symbol, has probably confused you.

When you call `: base()`, you aren't calling the interface's constructor. It does not have one. You are calling the constructor of `System.object`, that is a simple constructor with no arguments.

Try removing the interface and see that it still works.